# EclipseLink 2.5 still throwing IntegrityConstraintViolation when persisting entity, after record is deleted from database

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

This is the sequence:

1. App1: Persist Entity on database with ID=1. No problem.
2. App2: External application deletes that same record with ID=1. No problem.
3. App1: Tries to persist again the entity previous deleted by App2, here throws an exception saying "IntegrityConstraintViolation", as if the record were still in the database, and I'm inserting it twice, which is not.

The thing is that as I see, the EntityManager is using the cache to validate the Integrity f the database. And somehow, even after I call

`getEM().getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll(); or
getEM().clear();`

the EntityManager is keeping that record in cache somehow, and I'm running out of ideas about how to clear that cache. One workaround I found was to call from App1:

`getEM().remove(entity.class, id);`

and it effectively removes the record from the database and from the EntityManager cache too. But, this is not the point, it only proves that it's using the cache for validation, but the main problem persists, "I cannot persist the record again after being deleted from another application".

BTW, I also tried refreshing the entity, and does not work either. It throws an exception saying the Entity is not managed.

Anybody have any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Are steps 1 and 3 executed using the same instance of EntityManager, or are you creating a new instance for each operation?

Comment: Are you using persist or merge?  If it uses optimistic locking, try clearing the version field

Comment: Hi @DavidLevesque, yes it's using the same EntityManager for both operations, inserting and deleting. In fact, to include more information, the scenario where this occurs is when running Test Cases for several methods. What I call App1 is a `methodA` and App2 is the `tearDown` method of the Test Class. The interaction occurs between several methods and the `tearDown` method, where all the Test Cases create records on database for testing purposes and the `tearDown` method **cleans** the database so the next Test Case can start its execution on a clean database.

Comment: @Chris using persist of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally solved the situation**, this version of EclipseLink 2.5 behaves a bit different than previous versions, and this is one of the differences. The problem was that I was executing this line at the 'tearDown()' method of the TestClass:

```
em.CreateQuery("delete from mytable").executeUpdate();
```

to clean the tables in database. Even when this line effectively deletes the record from the database, if you're using the same EntityManager, then it will not remove it from the cache no matter what you do. So, I just moved the query and created a **@NamedQuery** annotation in **mytable** Entity class, and called the NamedQuery instead of executing the SQL directly. So, my code in the 'tearDown()' method ended up being:

```
em.CreateNamedQuery("emptyMyTableQuery").executeUpdate();
```

And the @NamedQuery:

```
@NamedQuery(name="emptyMyTableQuery", query="delete from mytable")
```

Now it works perfectly.

Honestly, even when in previous versions of EclipseLink this **does not** occur, I have to say that this new version 2.5 has several enhancements and improvements in several aspects, and few bugs fixed too. Well, hope this helps is somebody finds the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Does App2 commit the transaction?

IntegrityConstraintViolation is thrown from the database, so it implies the old row still exists on the database.

Turn logging on finest and include the log of the two apps and the full exception stack trace.

In general reincarnating objects is not normally a good idea.  It is better to create a new object with a new id, or at least detach/copy to old object.

If another application is accessing the same database, you may consider disabling caching,

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/How_to_disable_the_shared_cache%3F

Otherwise, if you just want to refresh the cache for this one object, first call find() to ensure the object is managed, then call refresh() to remove it from the shared cache. (you will then need to either detach() it, or clear() your EntityManager or create a new one).